# Multiple UnaryPredicates for std::all_of()

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, std

Is it possible to use a single call of `std::all_of()` and use multiple  elements/conditions or'd together? Or does this violate the function?

Example:

```
if(std::all_of(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0||1||2||3) == true)
{
   //do something
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: `std::all_of` takes a predicate like many other algorithms do. It's roughly the same complexity to check for one thing as it is to check for a few.

Comment: @chris That i understand. The question is if i can do a logical condition for the predicate as in the example.

Comment: No, just like how you can't do `0` etc. You're asking about a more complex version when the simple version doesn't even work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to use a predicate such as

```
vector<t> v;
if(std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const t& el){
    return el == 0 || el == 1 || el == 2 || el == 3;                         
};)
{
   //do something
}
```

to get the behavior you want.

---

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) you get that

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool all_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
```

where

> `p`   -   unary predicate .  The signature of the predicate function should
>   be equivalent to the following:
>
> `bool pred(const Type &a);`
>
> The signature does not need to have `const &`, but the function must not
>   modify the objects passed to it. The type `Type` must be such that an
>   object of type `InputIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly
>   converted to `Type`. ​

where the most important part for you is the signature of `pred`

```
bool pred(const Type &a);
```

which means that the functor/lambda/method that you use as `pred` should take a parameter of type `Type` and return a `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

The third argument is a single predicate, but you can compose multiple predicates together. With a lambda this looks like:

```
std::all_of(vector.begin(), vector.end(), [](auto &&v) {
    return v == 1 || v == 2 || v == 3 || v == 4;
})
```

The composition takes place such that the result of the composition itself is a predicate, i.e. a single function object.

---

Note that in your example `std::all_of(vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0||1||2||3)` you are not passing a predicate. A predicate is a *function* or *function object*. `0 || 1 || 2 || 3` is not a predicate and so this is not an example of a correct usage of `all_of`. This is not dependent on the use of `||`. Just passing a value such as `1` is also incorrect.